# An extra space added around attributes in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We are working on a web java web application. We have used html pages for UI. We are facing an issue after deploying the application in tomcat server. An extra space is added around all the attributes. The sample code after deployment is as follows.

```
<div class=" " id=" mytab ">
  <div class=" widget-title ">Profile</div>
  <br> <span id=" mainerr " class=" spanclass ">
  </span> <span id=" mainerr1 " class=" spanclass "></span>
</div>
```

The original file in server is not having space but when i check in browser inspect element option it became as above. Please help me to solve this. Because of this problem the id attribute is not getting reffered

Comment: is it in all major browser?

Comment: I checked in chrome and firefox. In both the browser i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to use proper DTD in html pages.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```